# Dynamic schema selection for Spring Data JPA repositories with schema coming from database

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

as the title says, I have an application (Spring Boot) which must execute some queries on specified objects on a SQL Server database. Such database having a single catalog and multiple schemas, which must be selected based on a previous query and some command line parameters.

I cannot seem to implement a strategy which involves Hibernate multi-tenancy, as most of the tutorials and answers on this site deal with schema names coming from a web request or an external parameter, while I need a database connection before creating the main multi-tenant EntityManager. So, I switched to a custom DataSource which tries to change the connection's default schema (using `ALTER USER... WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = ...`). But this also fails because the logged-in user does not have permission to alter his own default schema.

So I'm at a loss of what to do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create an EntityManager(Factory) per schema and put them in a map to choose from.

If you don't know the schemas before hand you can create EntityManager(Factory)s as soon as you learn about a schema.

that you can configure an EntityManagerFactory programatically.

Comment: I don't know in advance how many schemas there will be, nor what are they called. The correct schema must be retrieved from a predetermined global schema, for every query.

Comment: then create the EntityManager(Factory) as soon as you know the schema. Note, that you can configure an EntityManagerFactory programatically.

Comment: That I did, and it works, thanks a lot. Could you make this an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @Alessandro how did you fixed it with `@Entity` classes? As there are multiple dynamic schemas, and each entity can belong to every schema. Also if we omit schema name in `@Table` then it is throwing error. I am using PostgreSQL database.